# Question about Gauss' Determination of the first day of the year.

Tags: calendar-computations

On the wikipedia article
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Gauss.27_algorithm it explains the Gaussian Formula for calculating the first day of the year. I was wondering why the co-efficients are what they are. I understand the function, apart from this bit. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks In Advance!

Edit:
I found this article:
http://www.berndt-schwerdtfeger.de/bs/uploads/pdf/cal.pdf
but I can't figure out the third and fourth coefficients now. It shows the calculation but not how it got there.

Comment: I couldn't find a tag that suited this, sorry :/

Comment: There's in fact a ([tag:calendar-computations]) tag.

Comment: thanks, i've changed it now :)